# Writing plug-ins for Adobe (Reader and PhotoShop) using .NET(C#)

Tags: .net, plugins, adobe

I want to write plug-ins for Adobe products in .NET (C#) (specifically Acrobat Reader and PhotoShop). The requirement is to add a new command in the File menu. So for example in Acrobat Reader, I need to add a new "File >> Open My File" command that displays my dialog to open some file.

I have heard about the Adobe Development Kit. Is there a project type or some wizard in Visual Studio through which a plug-in can be created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no special SDK for Reader. Only one for both Acrobat Pro/Standard and Reader. Some functions may or may not be available -- depending on your target application.

The plug-in SDKs for Reader/Photoshop come with samples. And also Visual Studio wizards (at least for Acrobat 8 SDK -- they did). I am assuming that you'll get one for Photoshop as well. Please take a look at the documentation/samples bundled with the SDK.

The SDKs are essentially C/C++ APIs. So you'll need to use P/Invoke or some other similar hack to call this native  code from your .NET application.

Answer (score 3):

a simpler way would be to add the Photoshop COM .dll to your application via the COM tab.  I'm a newbie and I've done this with success.  2 simple methods to run are the PhotoshopWebImageGallery, and the PdfPresentation methods (takes an input folder and an output folder for the resulting pdf presentation.  There's also a "doJavaScript" method that takes a string with your JavaScript.  If you google Photoshop Javascript Scripting, the manual from Adobe should be one of the first entries.  I haven't tried the "doJavaScript" method yet, but I have seen the ImageGallery, and the PdfPresentation methods work!

Here are some good links on the topic as it pertains to JavaScript.

1. [At Adobe](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/scripting.html)
2. [At Rags](http://www.rags-int-inc.com)

The fella who runs this site just sent me back an email to some Photoshop Scripting questions I had today! Real good about responding promptly!

In theory one should be able to add that Photoshop COM .dll, the "doJavaScript" method, the examples provided and "make something happen".  Looks like this is kinda old and you may have it down pat by now!  If so share some image sharpening methods!!!
Good Luck!